# bash string replacement in a file

Tags: regex, bash, sed, wildcard

I am trying to replace some text in a file replacetest.xml

here is the part of the file I want to modify.

`<class name="replace_after_this_string">randomtext</class>`

I want to change the text `randomtext` with the text at the index of my array

```
orgs=( item1 item2 )
```

and overwrite the file with these modifications.

My main issues are with wildcards and the `sed` command. So here is what I tried

```
orgs=( item1 item2 )

SRC="name="'"replace_after_this_string"'">"
#need some sort of wildcard here


for i in "${orgs[@]}"
do
:
    # do whatever on $i
    DST=$SRC$i

    sed -e 's/$SRC/$DST/g' -i replacetest.xml

done
```

1) I need a wildcard to designate that I want to replace `randomtext` after identifying what will be in the variable `$SRC`

2) My sed statement doesn't do anything except print to command line verbatim, does not modify my file at all, even in what is printed to command line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think sed is the wrong tool for this, since it doesn't understand the structure of XML files, and as a result, your script will end up being rather brittle even if you can get it to work at all.  As [Brian Agnew suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12477998/223092) in his answer, [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) is a helpful tool for manipulating XML files.  For example, if your file (`12477913.xml`, say) is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
  <class name="replace_after_this_string">randomtext</class>
  <class name="not_for_replacing">some other text</class>
</foo>
```

... then this command:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u './/class[@name="replace_after_this_string"]' \
    -v 'REPLACED HERE' 12477913.xml
```

... would produce the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
  <class name="replace_after_this_string">REPLACED HERE</class>
  <class name="not_for_replacing">some other text</class>
</foo>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it doesn't answer your question directly, but I'd use something XML-aware for modifying XML files. That way you'll avoid issues with entity and character encoding, and maintain well-formedness.

It's worth checking out [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) as a command-line XML toolkit.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me adding an answer along similar lines, but with an example - I'd worked out an appropriate xmlstarlet invocation by the time I saw your answer, and was reluctant to discard it...

Comment: @MarkLongair - not at all. I've voted it up since an example is worthwhile